# How to geocode "current_user_sign_in_ip" after log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

So currently I have an application that is hosted on heroku.

I am using the devise gem for all user authentication

I want the user to be able to check their current location on a map and for this i am using the geocoder gem

However, After logging in the users ip is registered but their longitude and latitude values do not change and remain "nil".

If i go into my rails console and give the current_sign_up_ip a different value then it starts to work.

This is what my User.rb file looks like at the moment:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
     attr_accessor :firstname, :lastname

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
      :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
      :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook , :google_oauth2]

  geocoded_by :current_sign_in_ip
  after_validation :geocode

   def self.from_omniauth(auth)
     where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
       user.provider = auth.provider
       user.uid = auth.uid
       user.email = auth.info.email
       user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
       user.firstname = auth.info.firstname
     end
  end
end
```

And this is what my view that displays the map looks like at the moment:

```
<h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div style="'width: 800px">
   <div id = "map" style = "width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </div>


<script type="application/javascript">



handler = Gmaps.build('Google'); 
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers([
    {
      "lat": (<%= current_user.latitude %>),
      "lng": (<%= current_user.longitude %>),
      "picture": {
        "url": 
"https://i.pinimg.com/736x/4e/e8/fb/4ee8fbf4312a171c9e344abb30c65e21.jpg",
       "width":  32,
       "height": 32
  },
  "infowindow": "hello!"
}
  ]);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
    });
   </script>




<% else %>

<% end %>
```

So the problem I am having is that evne though the "current_sign_in_ip" has a value the longitude and latitude of the user at point is not being geocoded.

It works if I get the user to enter their current IP address while logging in

Answer (score 0):

I checked the docs of Geocoder gem, this seems to be the correct way to configure this. I think you need to debug the after_validation method, by adding a different after_validation that tests the geocode method, something like:

```
after_validation :geocode_test

def geocode_test
  binding.pry # or debug if you don't use pry
  geocode
end
```

There should be some reason it is not working correctly. It might be in your server log as well, have you checked it for errors?